# How to pass function without using &

Tags: c++

I often write code where I have the following scenario.

I have a (pure) function `f` and another function `g` which is templated so that it takes a callable object, say with similar type as `f`, as an argument.

Now often `f` is not super trivial but a couple of lines long and since it
is it is stateless I define `f` as a normal function. But then when passing `f` I have to write `&f` and I really dislike the syntax.

Another way would be to write a global lambda or a functor, that would fix my "& issue". But syntactically I prefer normal functions...

So is there a way to define `g` such that I can pass `f` as a normal function but avoid the `&`?

Comment: Maybe add some sample code to show what you are describing.

Comment: *"I have to write &f "* - Can you give an example? I honestly don't see a need for this; decay to a pointer should happen

Comment: [Works fine here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd9482f9a0496748).  Can we get an [mcve]?

Comment: I prefer `&f` syntax that C-inherited `f` syntax.

Comment: Did you mean class method/function instead of regular (free) function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to explicitly take the address of a function when passing it. As an example, the following code compiles and works:

```
template <typename F>
void foo(F f) { f(); }

void bar() { }

int main()
{
    foo(bar);
}
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wcSTvu0TYr9Pvnu6)

Comment: I was unaware of that, thanks!